# Database table data with different set of values

Tags: database-design, database-recommendation

I am trying to create a database table for my project but I stuck in this type of data.

The purpose is the admin can add, modify or insert types of questions and choices

example:

**Do you like pokemon?**

- Yes
- No

**Pick the pokemons you like**

[] charmander

[] pikachu

[] squirtle

[] bulbasaur

**Pick your starting pokemon:**

- charmander
- pikachu
- squirtle
- bulbasaur

**Why pikachu is so cute?**

---

Explanation here

---

Here is my table

Questions table

> id  |  question   |  type

Choices table

> id  |    choice   |  question_id

UserAnswers  table

> id  |    choice_id  | question_id  |  answer  |   userid

my problem is where to put the explanation of the user since it would be a large set of text? I am still very new in database designing and don't know what to do with this type of scenario. Please any recommendation for a good way to design my table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're on the right track.

I presume `questions.type` (NB `type` might be a reserved word and cause problems) will have the check constraint `check type in ('multiple_choice','free_text')` or something similar.

Then all you would need to do is rename your proposed `UserAnswers` to `UserMultipleChoiceAnswers` and drop the column `answer`, 
and create another table, `UserFreeTextAnswers` with columns `id, question_id, answer, user_id`.